# Installing VS Community 2015 installation locaiton

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to reinstall VS Community 2015, because it died after my upgrade to Win10... Unfortunately, I'm unable to modify/repair/uninstall the install. It fails each time.

I used Geek Uninstaller which removed the entries and now I'm able to get the install screen.

The challenge now is that it wants to install to D:\VSCommunity. I don't have a D-drive... How do I change the drive letter?

Comment: `subst d: c:\\`?

Comment: Hoping to find a way to tell VS install to go to a different place instead of tricking it.

Answer (score 0):

Something just got hosed in my system. Attempted 'subst d: c:\', but installation failed. Uninstall failed as well. Ended up doing a total reinstall of Win 10. Works now :).